# dot routine for scipy.sparse matrices produces error

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a [CSR matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
>> print type(tfidf)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

I want to take dot product of two rows of this [CSR matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
>> v1 = tfidf.getrow(1)
>> v2 = tfidf.getrow(2)
>> print type(v1)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

Both `v1` and `v2` are also CSR matrices. So I use `dot` subroutine:

```
>> print v1.dot(v2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cosine.py", line 10, in <module>
    print v1.dot(v2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 211, in dot
    return self * other
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 246, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

They are the rows of the same matrix, so their dimentions ought to match:

```
>> print v1.shape
(1, 4507)
>> print v2.shape
(1, 4507)
```

Why does `dot` subroutine not work?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your two matrices? Do they not match?

Comment: @Justin: The dimentions ought to be the same. They are the rows of the same matrix.

Comment: You can't do `1xn` dotted with `1xn`, it has to be `1xn` dotted with `nx1`.  How about `v1.dot(v2.transpose())`.

Comment: @Justin: Works! Thanks! Post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To perform a dot product of two row vectors, you have to transpose one.  the one to transpose depends on the result you're looking for.

```
import scipy as sp

a = sp.matrix([1, 2, 3])
b = sp.matrix([4, 5, 6])

In [13]: a.dot(b.transpose())
Out[13]: matrix([[32]])
```

Versus

```
In [14]: a.transpose().dot(b)
Out[14]: 
matrix([[ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 8, 10, 12],
        [12, 15, 18]])
```